# Which historical figure is attributed with the most death of his people?

Tags: hitler, stalin, genocide

I've heard friends of mine say that Stalin's reign produced more death than the Third Reich.  I have not been able to verify this anywhere.  Wikipedia does not offer a figure as to how many deaths Stalin is responsible for.  It even seems to say that no one is really sure.  But do we have a sense if Stalin is responsible for death on a greater magnitude than Hitler's?

Also, it would seem from a commenter that China had an even larger death toll.  Is that the largest, and is it attributable to one man, or very few people?

Comment: It would be of roughly the same *order of magnitude magnitude*: somewhere between 10 million to 25 million

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens do u have any sources or are you just speculating?

Comment: Are you asking about genocide? mass executions? civilian war casualities? These are three different questions.

Comment: And during the [Great Chinese Famine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Chinese_Famine) died 15- 40 millions people - It really depends on a detailed definition what you are looking for.

Comment: I think we should specify if we are talking about genocide, mass executions or civil wars? These terms are not the same and therefore the numbers would be different. Both Stalin and Hitler had different motives.
Regards,
Ivonne from [EssayDune.com](http://essaydune.com).

Comment: Fair point, @fdb.  I will edit the question.

Comment: Now you are broadening the question. This won't do. Downvoted.

Comment: Do you count reduced life expectancy? For instance, current Russia has some 20 years less male life expectancy than Western Europe. It can be attributed to Putin, for instance so that he "killed" millions this way. Western historians often attribute the same thing to Stalin.

Comment: Thanks @[Deer Hunter].  'this won't do'.  What does that mean?  How is this not a compelling question?

Comment: @Anixx If people were oppressed so much so that they passed on earlier, I would say that qualifies as death resposible to the oppressor.

Answer (score 1):

The number of executions under Stalin varies between 642 980 (source: Zuyev M.N. 2002. History of Russia Vol. 2: p.230) (the internal report on the number of convicted to death penalty to Khrushchev for 1921-1954) and 827 995 (source: Pozdnov M. Death penalty in the USSR in 1937-1938) for the entire Soviet rule (1917-1990), of which the majority of executions happened in 1937-1938.

[image]
Here is the report by Ministry of Internal Affairs made in December 1953 for the period 1921-1938. The ВМН column means executions.

Everything else can be attributed to Stalin only indirectly.

The Western and anti-Soviet propaganda (e.g, [Black Book of Communism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Book_of_Communism)) usually attributes to Stalin

- The famine in Ukraine. The archival sources show that the famine could bring about 2 million death, in Western propaganda this number exaggerated a lot. Western propaganda also makes a "genocide of Ukrainians" from this famine, despite evidence such as Stalin's correspondence that shows that Stalin was actively investigating the causes of the famine and took measures. Other anti-Soviet sources just blame Stalin for criminal negligence or call the famine an outcome of collectivization.
- The number of casualties in World War II. The western propaganda usually blames Stalin for too high casualties in the initial period of the war as well as often blames him for not predicting the German invasion well and/or blindly cooperating with Germany. Military casualties are usually intentionally mixed with civilian ones so to inflate numbers. So for all people dead due to Nazi genocide Stalin is blamed. He is also accused for shortages of the equipment in the military which allegedly led to higher casualties.
- The hunger deaths during the siege of Leningrad. The propaganda usually blames Stalin for refusing to evacuate the city.
- The number of people dead in prisons. Stalin ruled for a long period of time, so during his rule about 2 million people died in prisons. Statistics indicate that death rate in prisons under Stalin with exception of the years of war was not much different from deaths in modern Russia or other countries and was even smaller than the death rate among the general piopulation (this is because among the imprisoned were mostly young strong people). The total number of inprisoned was smaller per person than in modern USA and slightly greater than in modern Russia.
- Some sources (e.g. Dyadkin, “Unnatural Deaths in the U.S.S.R.: 1928-1954,”) go as far as to projecting the Imperial Russia's pre-revolutionary demographics on to Soviet time and estomating the population numbers that would be expected if the trend continued so to blame the difference in the population numbers on the Stalin's mismanagement or cruelty.

A notable piece of propaganda is the book "Europe. A History." by Norman Davies (1996). 
Here is the page where he gives the estimates of "the number of people killed in Soviet Russia and the Soviet Union 1917-1953 (excluding the losses 1939-1945)". He claims the estimates are after R. Medvedev and R.Conquest, the both sources from mid-1960s when Soviet archves were not yet available. Nevertheless, Davies arrives at the number more than twice that of Modvedev or Conquest each.

[image]

To see how ridiculous these numbers of "killed" are, lets consider the "deportations to Gulag".

According the report to Khrushchev of 01.02.1954 (you can see the [full text](http://www.alexanderyakovlev.org/fond/issues-doc/1009140) at the site of N.Yakolev's foundation, a very anti-Stalinist and anti-Soviet institution).
[image]

the total number of the convicted 1921-1954 was approximately 3 777 000. Of which 765 180 convicted for counter-revolutionary crimes were sentenced to excile or deportation abroad. Also (according the prevuous report) at least 745 000 were executed. This leaves 2 660 000 sentenced to imprisonment (of which only a part were sent to Gulag). Well according to Davis, during the deportation to Gulag were killed 17 million. Apparently some people were killed up to 10 times!

Moreover, the average death rate in Gulag is also well known from the archive data:

[image]

Sources: Zemskov V.N. Gulag. Sociological research. 1991. #6 pp.14-15; for 1931-1940 - ГАРФ (Russian state archive), ф.9414, оп.1, д.1155, л.2; д.2740, л.1, 5, 8, 14, 26, 38, 42, 48, 58, 96-110

Note also that many who died during the war died not due to maltreatment but because they volunteered to the front (that would reduce the term of their sentence).

Comment: I think the question was about genocide (killing specific ethnic groups).

Comment: @fdb well Stalin has been accused only of genocide of Ukrainians through the famine and this is covered in the answer. Definitely the famine was not intentional and not welcomed by Stalin (as show the Stalin's correspondence) and affected not only Ukraine. There were also deportations of certain ethnic groups (Crinmean Tatars, Chechens) under Stalin during the war but there is no evidence that these deportations were accompanied with exceptional death rates or were intended as genocides.

Comment: Why is the downvote?

Comment: 20 million dead. It was only indirect, could happen to anyone...!

Comment: more revisionist history by Comrade Anixx

Comment: @Ne Mo any sourrce for 20 million dead? Of what they died?

Comment: @jwenting  this history is based on archival data. Do u have another history?

Comment: @fdb `genocide (killing specific ethnic groups)` if we take the number of ethnic _deportations_ it rises upto a few million. But if we talk only about ethnic _killings_, it would be thousands.

Comment: @user4419802. Thanks, that actually answers the question.

Comment: http://www.ibtimes.com/how-many-people-did-joseph-stalin-kill-1111789 20 million is considered a conservative estimate...

Comment: @Ne Mo the source you linked calls 20 the million non-combatant deaths as "a guess"

Comment: @NeMo `20 million is considered a conservative estimate` What a wonderful peace of propaganda that article is! `[Stalin] An amoral psychopath and paranoid with a gangster’s mentality` and so on. A nice source for your knowledge in history.

Comment: My problem with the above is that the numbers written in the Russian document pictured _simply cannot be true numbers_. As in, "the total number of convicted ... was 3,777,000. The 7,001st person was juuuusst about to be convicted when the judge said "whoops, nope, can't do this, we need a nice round number."

Comment: @CGCampbell  regarding the total numbers the report to Khruschev says "approximately".

Comment: @Anixx and that is why a question like this cannot truly be answered, because _no one knows_ and the West says something and the East calls bullshit, and the East says something and the West calls bullshit.

Comment: @CGCampbell it is now what the East "says". It is an internal document, a report to Khrushchev. Even if the numbers are not exact, the total number cannot be 2 orders of magnitude greater. The number of Gulag inmates never much exceeded 1.7 million. Davies claims that the number of killed in Gulag, 10 millions was 5 times greater than ever was convicted.

Comment: @Anixx, it may be a language barrier issue, but you are totally misrepresenting that article by implying it casts doubt on the 20 million number as too high. The article, wrong or right, says that is a likely minimum. Rather than bother to debate with Russian propaganda, which must nowadays sanitise Stalin to burnish the Putinite ideology, I suggest the OP take a look at this website. Only a website, no better than wikipedia, but the claims are directly sourced...

Comment: ...The Stalin-maximisers have come up with numbers around 30 million, the Stalin-minimisers' estimates cluster around 8 million. Rather more than the 'mere' 700,000 murder victims Stalin openly admitted to.

Comment: "by implying it casts doubt on the 20 million number as too high." - where you saw me implying this? "the claims are directly sourced.." - in the article you cited there are links 1) to Medvedev (the source is from 1960s, before archives opened), 2) Conquest (the same), 3) Davies who references Medvedev and Conquest without adding anything from himself 4) Dyadkin which counts anything rather than the killings (unborn children, lower life expectancy etc).

Comment: "The Stalin-maximisers have come up with numbers around 30 million, the Stalin-minimisers' estimates cluster around 8 million" - science is not just taking maximum and minimum between unsubstantiated claims and guesses and finding the average.

Comment: On what planet is it scientific to believe in Soviet internal reports, which contained just as much self-deception as any of its propaganda? What good reason is there to credit the idea that your 700,000 number gives a full account of everybody who died in the gulags? And how can it be remotely sane to say that the millions who died as a result of collectivisation were Stalin's victims 'only indirectly'?

Comment: @Ne Mo self-deception? For what purpose? Khrushchev wanted to exaggerate the numbers for the upcoming XX party congress. There is no evidence that any Soviet archives has been forged or not reliable historical source. There is no serious historian that disputes their reliability. Is it more reliable for you to think that Staling killed one third of the population of the country instead and that in Gulag died 10 for each 1 survived?

Comment: I'll give this one an "A for effort" plus a willingness to use actual human logic.

Comment: @NeMo `the Stalin-minimisers' estimates cluster around 8 million. Rather more than the 'mere' 700,000 murder victims Stalin openly admitted to.` As @Anixx pointed, 700000 is the number of _executions only_. I bet, anyone saying about 8 mln. or more, _already added_ all the people died in GULag, all the victims of famine etc. Talking about 8 mln. _executions_ is nonsense due to demographical statistic.

Comment: I think this would be a great answer if it was presented neutrally and left off the propaganda judgements. Original documents showing the findings of Khrushchev era internal Soviet reports are certainly of interest and relevance whether or not they represent the true numbers.

Comment: @Ne Mo "Stalin openly admitted"? Don't you see the mark "top secret" on the documents?

Comment: Nobody said that there were 8 million executions, just that more than 700000 people were deliberately killed.